# Ansible uri with faild_when and loop fails

Tags: ansible

I have a problem with a loop and failed_with in ansible. I don't know why.
The actual failed_when is much more complex, I know i could use status_code in this case.

It is my goal to parse the json response from a local api for multiple (dynamic list I got early from the api) objects and fail if it is not a response I expect.

```
- name: "get status for items"
  uri:
    url: https://{{inventory_hostname}}/status
    method: POST
    body_format: json
    body: "{'index': {{item.index}}"
  register: this
  failed_when: "this.status != 200"
  loop: "{{ item_list.json | json_query('[?state== `UNDEFINED`]') }}"
```

I get the error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'this' is undefined
  
    The error appears to be in '/home/blablup/Devel/ansible/roles/myrole/tasks/update.yml': line 48, column 3, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
  
    The offending line appears to be:
  
  
    - name: "get status for items"
      ^ here
```

But if I read the documentation it should work this way. Also if I look at this: [Using `failed_when` on a `with_items` task depending on return codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981863/using-failed-when-on-a-with-items-task-depending-on-return-codes) example, failed_when should be evaluated for every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce the behavior you've described. If I wrap your task in sufficient code to run it, like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    item_list:
      json:
        - state: UNDEFINED
          index: 0
        - state: okay
          index: 1
        - state: UNDEFINED
          index: 2
  tasks:
    - name: "get status for items"
      uri:
        url: http://localhost:5000/status
        method: POST
        body_format: json
        body: "{'index': {{item.index}}"
      register: this
      failed_when: "this.status != 200"
      loop: "{{ item_list.json | json_query('[?state== `UNDEFINED`]') }}"
```

And provide a server that will return either a `200` or a `400` response:

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/status", methods=["POST"])
def status():
    if b"2" in request.data:
        return make_response("failed", 400)
    else:
        return make_response("okay", 200)
```

Then running your playbook produces the expected behavior (it succeeds when the server delivers a `200` response, and fails when the server returns a non-`200` response):

```
TASK [get status for items] *****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'foo', 'state': 'UNDEFINED', 'index': 0})
failed: [localhost] (item={'name': 'qux', 'state': 'UNDEFINED', 'index': 2}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content_length": "6", "content_type": "text/html; charset=utf-8", "date": "Wed, 12 Oct 2022 00:10:05 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "failed_when_result": true, "item": {"index": 2, "name": "qux", "state": "UNDEFINED"}, "msg": "Status code was 400 and not [200]: HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST", "redirected": false, "server": "Werkzeug/2.2.2 Python/3.10.7", "status": 400, "url": "http://localhost:5000/status"}
```

I'm using Ansible core version 2.12.6.

---

Unrelated to your question, but this looks suspicious:

```
body: "{'index': {{item.index}}"
```

You're not delivering a JSON request body (JSON does not use single quotes and your brackets aren't balanced). You want something like this:

```
body: {
  "index": "{{ item.index }}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I think it was my bad json data. After I fixed it, it worked like expected.